# Find text enclosed by character multiples times

Tags: regex, perl

**The problem:**

Find pieces of text in a file enclosed by `@`

Input:

```
@abc@ abc @ABC@
cba @cba@ CBA
```

Output:

```
@abc@ @ABC@
@cba@
```

I've tried the following:

```
cat test.txt | perl -ne 'BEGIN { $/ = undef; } print $1 if(/(@.*@)/s)."\n"'
```

But this results in:

```
@abc@ abc @ABC@
cba @cba@
```

Additional:
I was not complete. The goal of the above is the replace the characters between the @ with something else:
a should become chr(0x430)
b should become chr(0x431)
c should become chr(0x446)
A should become chr(0x410)
B should become chr(0x411)
C should become chr(0x426)
so with the above input in mind it should result in:
`абц abc АБЦ`
`cba цба CBA`

Sorry for my imcompleteness. Thanks Kluther

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `(@.*@)` is that `*` is greedy: it matches the largest amount possible.  Thus it will match everything between the first `@` in the string and the last one.

You can make it non-greedy with `(@.*?@)`.  However, a better approach is to match everything that is not `@` in between:

```
 (@[^@]*@)
```

If you want to match every occurrence instead of the first one, you also need to use the `/g` modifier and modify your code to use a loop:

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN { $/ = undef; } print $1 while(/(\@[^@]*\@)/gs); print "\n"'
```

Answer (score 0):

use pattern like this

```
@[a-zA-Z]+@
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
cat test.txt | perl -pe 's/(?:(@ )|^[^@]).*?(?: (@)|$)/$1$2/g'
```

Comment: this results in @abc@ @ABC@ cba @cba@ so the third entry must be left out somehow

Comment: @Kluther, no, it actually results in "@abc@  @ABC@  @cba@"

Comment: show me your input file. I just tried it again and same result.

Comment: Ok, I see you edited your question - now I know those are two separate lines. See my updated answer.

Comment: General rule: don't use replacement for matching tasks. This adds a lot more complexity and is a lot less efficient, all just to get the looping effect of `s///g`.

Answer (score 0):

Use non-greedy search `.+?` or `/(\@([^@]*)\@)/gsm`.

```
cat test.txt | perl -ne 'BEGIN { $/ = undef; } print $1." " while(/(\@([^@]*)\@)/gsm); print "\n";'
```

Comment: This results in the same as the origional.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
$ perl -pe '@a=$_=~/@[^@]+@/g; $_="@a";' file
@abc@ @ABC@ @cba@
```

Comment: This works also. I'm not sure which solution I will use. I have to do some processing afterwards. But thanks